# If $H\le G$ is a cyclic subgroup, must $[H : H\cap gHg^{-1}] = [gHg^{-1} : H\cap gHg^{-1}]$?

Tags: group-theory

If $H\le G$ is a cyclic subgroup, then must it be true that
$$[H : H\cap gHg^{-1}] = [gHg^{-1} : H\cap gHg^{-1}]$$

Note that if either index is infinite, then $H\cap gHg^{-1}$ must be trivial, so both indices are infinite, so it suffices to restrict to the case when both indices are finite.

Ideally one would like to conjugate by $g$ to send a system of coset representatives for the first index to a system of coset representatives for the second index, but it's not clear that $H\cap gHg^{-1}$ is normalized by $g$.

Comment: Would the Baumslag-Solitar group BS(1,2) provide a counterexample? It is given by $\langle a,b\mid a^b=a^2\rangle$, and take $H=\langle a\rangle$.